# Arduino Analog to Digital Conversion from 56V DC Batteries

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a problem, I am using 56V DC combined batteries system. I get ADC values comes to Arduino like 211, 217 etc... I have to find out when the DC volt drop to 42V. How do i know the digital value for the ADC from Aruino.

Comment: Your code and circuit please, or we are just not able to help you. Ypu cannot measure voltages greater than 5V with the Uno, so you need circuitry to divide the voltage down to that range

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using Li-Ion batteries in 14s configuration. You'll want to measure voltages up to around 60 V while charging. With a bit of safety margin, I'd set it up to measure up to 72V without damaging the Arduino - which can measure voltages up to 5 V, but the input on that pin should never exceed 5.5 V.

To bring your battery voltage down to something the Arduino can use, you'll need to use a voltage divider, as [chrisl suggested](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72739/arduino-analog-to-digital-conversion-from-56v-dc-batteries#comment159022_72739).

[image: Schematic, allaboutcircuits.com]

With R1 = 10 kOhm and R2 = 680 Ohm, you'd get readings up to an input voltage of 78 Volts.

With `analogRead()` returning values between 0 and 1023, your 42 V cutoff would be around 546.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: this is going to get math-heavy**

Ok. So you have a battery with a voltage divider on it, and you are using the Aruino ADC to read the output of that voltage divider. And you want to "back-calculate" the battery voltage from the ADC reading.

First let's look at exactly what happens with a voltage divider and just how it works. For that we'll turn to good ol' Ohm's Law.

Rule number one is that two resistors in series *sum* their resistances. So if you have a 10kΩ and 680Ω resistor in series (as suggested in @towe's answer) the total resistance is 10680Ω.  We'll use this arrangement as our example.

Now Ohm's Law states that the current flowing through a resistive load is directly proportional to the voltage across it. So for a fixed resistance and a given voltage we can calculate the current that will be flowing through the resistors.  That formula is:

## ***I=V/R***

So for a voltage of 56V and a resistance of 10680Ω we can say that the current is 56/10680 amps - or about 5.24mA.

Great. But so what? Well, now we can reverse the formula and find the voltage across a given resistance for that specific current. Which we can do for, for example, the 680Ω resistor.  We know that the same current is flowing through both resistors (since they are in series), so flipping the formula around we get:

## ***V=I×R***

So at 0.00524 amps and 680Ω that's 0.00524×680 = 3.57V.  We can do the same for the 10kΩ resistor: 0.00524×10000 = 52.43V.  And oh look - if we add those two voltages together, what do we get? We get 56V. The resistors have divided the voltage into two portions.

You can combine those two formulae together to give you:

## ***V<sub>OUT</sub> = V<sub>IN</sub> × (R<sub>2</sub> / (R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>))***

And if we move the V<sub>IN</sub> to the left hand side we get:

## ***V<sub>OUT</sub> / V<sub>IN</sub> = (R<sub>2</sub> / (R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>))***

And that is known as the *transfer function*, or the ratio of the input to output voltage of the voltage divider.

For a 10kΩ (R<sub>1</sub>) and 680Ω (R<sub>2</sub>) resistor pair we get 680/10680 = 0.0637.

And that is the "magic number" we want to calculate back from the ADC to the battery voltage.  Whatever the voltage we read at the ADC the battery voltage is the reciprocal of that number times bigger (reciprocal is "one over the value").  The reciprocal of 0.0637 is 15.7.  So if you read the value from the ADC then convert that into a voltage relative to the internal reference voltage (approximately 5V for a normal Arduino) then multiply that voltage by 15.7 you will get your battery voltage.

So next is to get the ADC voltage. And again, it's all ratios.  The ADC gives you a number that is a ratio of the incoming voltage to the reference (5V) voltage.  At 1023 you get "5V minus 1 LSB", so about 4.995V. We don't need that kind of accuracy for this, really, so we'll just call it 5V.

Say you read 482 from the ADC, if you convert that into a voltage you take the ratio 482/1024 and multiply it by the reference voltage (1024 is the range of a 10-bit ADC - you would change that for other types of ADC):

## ***V<sub>IN</sub> = 482 / 1024 × 5 = 2.35V***

Multiply that by our "magic number" 15.7 and you get 36.95V - and that's the battery voltage.